# Angular - change the content from Radio button on submit button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events, dom-events

I'm stuck in a problem where I want to change a div based on which radio button is clicked. I've been using it without form tag and it changes as soon as I click on the button, NOT ON SUBMIT BUTTON. **I want it the other way, i.e, it should submit value on button click and then changes the content**, any suggestion what I might've been doing wrong.

It should show different questions based on the radio I select. In the case of **YES** it shows other and in case of **NO**, another. Then further questions will be the same. **(This logic works fine)**

```
onItemChange(value) {
    console.log(value)
    this.previous = false;
    if (value == 1) {
      this.yesOption = true;
    } else if (value == 0) {
      this.noOption = true;
    }
  }
```

**Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4lhhxh**

Comment: In `onItemChange` you're changing the value of `this.previous` and in the HTML you're using that to conditionally render `Question 2`.

Comment: Yes, That was based on condition to show respective div on respective radio click. I couldn’t figure out any other way to do this. Any help would be great

Comment: I want to help but I'm confused on what exactly you're trying to do. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Basically, **yes and no** options **show 2 different questions** and then same onwards from 3rd question, meaning only second question is different for both options. In case of yes, it's different and in case of no, different.

What I want is,
As I click on a radio button it changes the div, I want this to happen on next button click. It shouldn't just change the div as I select a radio button. I hope you get it now

Comment: Okay got you, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pngsxs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) that implements what you asked.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h3>{{ 'Question ' + (currentQuestionIndex+1) }}</h3>
    <div>
        <div *ngIf="currentQuestionIndex === 0">
            <div class="">
                <label>Yes</label>
                <input value="yes" [(ngModel)]="firstAnswer" type="radio">
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <label>No</label>
                <input value="no" [(ngModel)]="firstAnswer" type="radio">
            </div>
        </div>

        <p *ngIf="currentQuestionIndex > 1">Normal question</p>
        <p *ngIf="currentQuestionIndex === 1">You selected {{ firstAnswer === 'yes' ? '"Yes"' : '"No"' }} for question 1</p>
    </div>
    <button (click)="next()">Next</button>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  questionsLength = 5;
  questions = Array(this.questionsLength);
  currentQuestionIndex = 0;
  firstAnswer;
  next() {
    if (this.currentQuestionIndex < this.questionsLength - 1) {
      this.currentQuestionIndex++;
    }
  }
}
```

You can use `ngModel` on the radio input and later use that variable to check what has been selected.

**Update**

If you want to display some divs conditionally:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="currentQuestionIndex === 1">
          <div *ngIf="firstAnswer === 'yes'">You selected "Yes" for question 1</div>
          <div *ngIf="firstAnswer === 'no'">You selected "No" for question 1</div>
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: What if I want 2 separate divs like I used in my demo for 2nd questions?

Comment: @Kenny.k You can use nested divs and display them conditionally.

Comment: This looks like working for this scenario, I've another case. Is there any way we can discuss in chat?

Comment: Okay, join this https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216934/angular

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a form, you need to either:

1. Store the value somewhere else using [(ngModel)] (don't forget to change configuration to Standalone), or..
2. Have an object with values and assign individual values in `onItemChange` callback (if you don't want to use [(ngModel)]
3. Use @ViewChild to reference the input and get the value (which is.. ugly)

In any case, the logic you currently have in the `onItemChange` would have to be moved to the `nextQuestion`.

Per your request, I have made an example on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2mwzxd